# How would I paginate multiples of 20 correctly based on query params?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, pagination

When the user inputs an `offSet` value in the query param in the URL, oddly enough, when `$take = 20;` and `$page = 1;` - this is when it displays the relevant data, but I'm not sure why numbers like `2, 4, 5, 10` won't work. So what's wrong with my code?

```
$results = $response->json()['results'];

collect($results);
$page = $request->get('offSet');
$take = 20;
$skip = ($page - 1) * $take;
$paginationResults = collect($results)->skip($skip)->take($take)->all();
    
dd(paginationResults);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the chunk methods of collection

```
$results = collect($result);
$outputs = $results->chunck(20)[$request->input('offset')];
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like a great solution honestly!  But I keep getting this error: `Error: Call to a member function chunk() on array`.  I'm not sure why.  I tried switching it to `$request->get('offSet');` but still got the same output.  Btw, you spelled it wrong!

Comment: have you add the previous line ?